# Logical OR without using numpy.logical_or

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logical-operators

To know the elements of a numpy array that verifies two conditions, one can use the operator `*`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,10,2],[2,-6,8]])
>>> a
array([[ 1, 10,  7],
       [ 2, -6,  8]])
>>> (a <= 6) * (a%2 == 0) # elements that are even AND inferior or equal to 6
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

But how about OR? I tried to do this:

```
>>> (a%2 == 0) + (a <= 6) - (a%2 == 0) * (a <= 6)
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

but the result is false for the elements that verifies both conditions. I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't see the OR operator.

Comment: Arithmetic operations on numpy booleans are cheesy, it is not the best of ideas to rely on them. Plus they make your code obscure and hard to interpret. If dealing with boolean arrays, use the bitwise operators: `&` for and, `|` for or, `^` for xor and `~` for not.

Comment: In case an answer solved your problem, please accept it as the solution like [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/4367286)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the subtraction.
The point is that `+` already behaves like the `or` operator

```
>>(a%2==0)+(a<=6)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

because "`True+True=True`".

When you subtract `(a<=6)*(a%2==0)` you turn all elements which satisfy both conditions into `false`.

It is easiest when you just do

```
>>(a<=6)|(a%2==0)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: My opinion only, but `|` should always be preferred over `+`. When I see `+` I start wondering why we are adding stuff together, or if in fact we are concatenating stuff. As soon as I see `|` I think of bitwise_or which I closely associate with logical_or.

Answer (score 2):

@plonser's answer is the correct one: use `+`.

If you wanted to use multiplication again, you could remember that one of De Morgan's laws tells you that

```
A or B
```

is logically equivalent to

```
not ( not A and not B )
```

So in NumPy you *could* write:

```
>>> ~(~(a%2 == 0) * ~(a <= 6))
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

But this isn't particularly readable.